# LinearLayoutManager cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, dependency-injection, dagger-2, mvp

I'm working with Dagger 2 and while creating a new Fragment I seem to have this error. I've been trying various things but I haven't been able to fix this message at all.

android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor

It seems like it should be straight forward being I am referencing [Mindorks MVP Project on Github](https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-mvp-architecture).

Here is my Fragments code, let me know what else to post if it is needed or if this is obvious.

```
public class HomePageFragment extends BaseFragment implements
    HomeMvpView {

@Inject
HomeMvpPresenter<HomeMvpView> mPresenter;

@BindView(R.id.featuredRecyclerView)
RecyclerView featuredRecyclerView;

@Inject
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

@Inject
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager2;

@Inject
FeaturedAdapter featuredAdapter;

public static HomePageFragment newInstance() {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    HomePageFragment fragment = new HomePageFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_page, container, false);

    ActivityComponent component = getActivityComponent();

    if (component != null) {
        component.inject(this);
        setUnBinder(ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView));

        mPresenter.onAttach(this);

    }
    return rootView;
}


@Override
protected void setUp(View view) {
    featuredRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.featuredRecyclerView);

    //setup Adapter
    mLayoutManager2 = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    //mLayoutManager2.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    featuredRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    featuredRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    featuredRecyclerView.setAdapter(featuredAdapter);
}
}
```

Comment: LinearLayoutManager doesn't have an @Inject annotated constructor.  It can't because its part of the framework.  It also doesn't have a no parameter constructor.  That means you need to make a provider function in a module somewhere to provider a correctly instantiated LinearLayoutManager.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll try putting in this code to my Activity Module and see where I can get - @Provides
    LinearLayoutManager provideLinearLayoutManager(AppCompatActivity activity) {
        return new LinearLayoutManager(activity);
    }

Comment: That ended up mostly solving it, my Adapter also threw an error because I didn't have a provider in the Activity Module for that either, plus I had a broken feature in my Main Activity.